# Is Dr. Culber the Chief Medical Officer on Discovery?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery

In *Star Trek: Discovery*, Dr. Culber is the face of the medical team to the audience, largely given his connection to Stamets. He's usually the one that is present when a medical emergency takes place. However, he usually works alone, and I don't recall him actually giving orders to someone.

Does Dr. Culber hold the role of Chief Medical Officer on board the *USS Discovery*? Or is he just a subordinate who is unusually active in the ship's proceedings?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Culber is not the CMO.

We have not met the CMO, nor any medical officer that appears to be Dr. Culber's superior, but on one occasion Culber says the CMO needs his assistance.

> Stamets: Aren't there actual people on this ship requiring your attention, doctor?
>
> Culber: Actually, the CMO does need my help with an Andorian tonsillectomy.

It is possible the tonsillectomy was invented to escape the situation at Stamet's suggestion, but it doesn't make any sense for Culber to invent a CMO.

I was unable to find a video clip but I found a reference on [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Choose_Your_Pain_(episode)) that also documents the exchange.

> Stamets asks Culber if there is someone on Discovery who requires his attention and the doctor states that he is due to help the ship's chief medical officer with an Andorian tonsillectomy.

Incidentally, tonsillectomies, or references to them, are still common enough in the 23rd and 24th centuries to warrant [their own Memory Alpha page](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Tonsillectomy).

Comment: I don't suppose they ever said who *is* the CMO?

Comment: The CMO hasn't been shown, nor the Chief Engineer or the senior Science Officer.

Comment: Memory Alpha says the reference to an Andorian tonsillectomy is in The Butcher's Knife Cares Not for the Lamb's Cry. I looked briefly on YouTube and could not find a video clip.

Comment: @ThomasOwens I never saw that but I saw multiple references to Choose Your Pain. I added them to the answer so you can verify.

Comment: Also, is it me or has Discovery demonstrated that it is futile to write a show about a starship while focusing on "lower decks" characters because the writing will inevitably require them to become the bridge crew?

Comment: @JDoe If you raise the stakes high enough that the captain and bridge crew need to know about it, it’s hard to justify them not getting involved every week. I guess you could make it so the lower deck group is some sort of specialist team (as with the video game *Star Trek Voyager: Elite Force*), but that’s very different than the sort of story *Discovery* wants to tell.

Comment: The [Discovery personnel page on Memory Alpha](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Discovery_unnamed_000#Unnamed_000) actually makes it more explicit with a remark on the CMO character: "As far as it is understood, this character not appeared in the series."

Comment: @JDoe: It hasn't. Rather, it has demonstrated that it is futile to write a show about a starship with a crew complement of more than 100 people while absolutely focusing on about 5 people and a story arc that doesn't leave any time to get acquainted with the ship and the universe around it. Symptoms of that include (but are not limited to) the conspicuous absence of any medical personnel during most of Stamets's experiments, the frequent impression that the new-found chief of security is a one-man department, exotic and never-before seen alien bridge crew members for mere eye-candy, ...

Comment: ... apparently without even a bit of a consistent backstory in the series bible (e.g. [Airiam](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Airiam)), and recurring characters that have a name (in the script, at least) and even seem to have some kind of superficial "character arc" going on (what's that with [Detmer](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Keyla_Detmer)'s implants?), yet contribute little more than background actors.

Comment: @JDoe remember that in TNG season 1 there was no consistent chief of security. There's plenty of time in S2 for these people to be introduced.

Comment: @monkjack *But it's not Culber!* jfc

Comment: Exactly. There's time for the CMO to be introduced in season 2. Which is what I wrote - jfc indeed.

Comment: @monkjack: I think you mean "chief engineer". Tasha Yar was the chief of security for much of season 1. While she left a bit early, I think the chief engineer (sometimes apparently even more than one of them) make for a much better example of "no consistent" in TNG's season 1.

Comment: Yes I did mean CoE.